# MySQL password not taking after new account creation

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu-12.04

I'm running MySQL 5.5 on Ubuntu Linux 12.04.  I set MySQL up with a root user and two accounts to access the db with using Workbench.  The root user works just fine and I can use it to access the DB from Workbench and other programs (like RapidAnalytics), but when I try and access the DB with my other two accounts it will recognize the user, but it won't recognize the password.  I know I've entered them correctly, I've reset them a few times, I'm 99.99% certain I'm putting the right password in.  On top of that, I've set up both users as DBAs, it made no difference.  I made sure they had schema privledges, still nothing (though I may have done that last one wrong. I Just went into the users panel in Workbench and used the wizard they had there...)

I set a MySQL DB up on Windows 7 in the last few days, and that one works just fine.  I'm quite certain I followed the same procedure...

At any rate, I have two questions.

Firstly, I read on another thread that this happens sometimes when more than one version of MySQL is installed on Linux.  But I'm kind of new to Linux and I'm not sure how to figure out if I have more than one version installed.  Can someone please advise if that is a good theory and if so, how to go about checking for what I have installed?

Secondly, well, I'm really just out of ideas.  If someone could point me in a good direction...I'm just not sure what to ask Google anymore.

Comment: can you share the commands you used to create the two users and also the command you used to reset their passwords? 

What does the command  `SHOW GRANTS FOR '<user>'@'%';` show?

Comment: I ran this `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'Jcarr'@'%';` and was told there are no grants given to this user.  Which seems problematic, how would that affect my password though?

Comment: @ShireeshJ - I did all of the commands from MySQL Workbench.  Perhaps that is the problem?

Comment: It can mean that you created the users but did not grant them any permissions on the database. How did you arrive at the conclusion that error is because of password? Also to see if multiple mysql servers are running, you can run `ps aux | grep mysqld` and see if there are two processes running.

Comment: I eventually figured it out.  I just needed to flush the privledges after changing them...I'm a bit new at this, sometimes I forget the basics.